# E-mail Link (passwordless) authentication with Firebase in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I am having a hard time trying to understand how the **passwordless** feature works with Firebase.
I am experimenting with [this code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/e38a7c5da9aa434648620baa7a4fc8e4558fe8bc/authentication/AuthenticationExampleSwift/PasswordlessViewController.swift#L43-L53) (from the Firebase documentation), and I can't manage to make it work.

- The app *successfully* sends the email to the email address provided,
- I *successfully* receive the email with a link in it,
- It *successfully* opens the app when I tap it,

**But no user is created nor connected afterwards**

(line 43)  `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: self.link)`

This line throws an error at runtime, as `self.link` is void. Which makes sense to me. What is supposed to make it change ?

I read the [documentation about this feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth), about [dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/), about [passing state in email action](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions#passing_statecontinue_url_in_email_actions), but I still must be missing something important.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: `self.link` should be populated with the incoming FDL deep link. You can parse that link with FDL or get it yourself. Make sure you setup your FDL domain and configure your associated domain in your app, so you can properly detect it.

Comment: I configured both, but how do I actually parse the link ? Why isn’t the solution present in the documentation ?

Comment: Check this page on how to get the deep link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app. After you get it, you can pass it in `signInWithEmail`